# Can you call "classmate" someone who attends the same institute as you?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Say you want to become a private investigator. You go to a detective training institute ... Can you call classmate someone who attend the same courses as you do?

I'm hesitant to do this because according to Oxford Dictionary:

> a fellow member of a class at **school, college, or university.**

It doesn't say institute.

But maybe this doesn't matter as long as there is a classroom?

If you can't call such person "classmate," what should you call them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

College is a synonym of [institute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/institute).  If the institute is focused on training a skillset and offers classes to that effect, having students call each other classmates would be appropriate.

If you want to avoid that, you could use [colleague](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colleague) or [peer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peer).